# In a Raster object, how to set the mean to NA if there are too many NAs in one cell?

Tags: r, mean, na, r-raster, terra

I am working with environmental data in the Raster format. I have one Raster object where every layer corresponds to a specific time step of observations.

The final objective is to calculate the mean of every cell across the temporal dimension. However, since I have many NAs in the data, I would like to set the mean to NA if there are too many NAs in the timeseries of the specific cell. This way I make sure that the calculated mean is robust, i.e. derived from a sufficient number of actual observations (e.g. I don't have one mean value calculated with 100 observations and another one based on 3 observations and 97 NAs).

In the example below, I would like to set the mean of NA if there are 2 or more NAs in the timeseries.

```
s <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=30)
set.seed(1)
values(s) <- rnorm(size(s), 10)
s[3] <- NaN # setting a cell to NA (across all layers)
s[[4]] <- NaN # setting a layer to NA
s[[1]][1] <- NaN # setting some random individual cells to NA
s[[5]][4] <- NaN
mn <- mean(s, na.rm = TRUE) # na.rm = FALSE would just set to NA any mean containing a single NA or more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=30)
set.seed(1)
values(s) <- sample(c(1:10, NA), size(s), replace=TRUE)
```

You can count the NAs and then use a threshold to mask the original data

```
sna <- sum(is.na(s))
x <- mask(s, sna > 2, maskvalue=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `app` (sort of a `SpatRaster` version of `apply`) to find the number of NAs in each cell across layers and then set the cells of your `mn` raster with too many NAs to NA:

```r
nas <- app(s, \(x) sum(is.na(x)))
mn[nas >= 2] <- NA

round(as.matrix(mn, wide=T))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]   NA   10   NA   NA   10   10   10   10   10    10
#  [2,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    11
#  [3,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
#  [4,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
#  [5,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
#  [6,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
#  [7,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
#  [8,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
#  [9,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
# [10,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
```

I had to modify your initial code slightly to make it work:

```r
library(terra)
s <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=30)
set.seed(1)
values(s) <- rnorm(size(s), 10)
s[3] <- NaN 
s[[4]][] <- NaN   # here I had to add []
s[[1]][1] <- NaN
s[[5]][4] <- NaN
mn <- mean(s, na.rm = TRUE)
```